# How can I delete cascade from two tables in sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

I want to be able to deleted an officer from the officer table and on doing so it will automatically delete the officers Investigations from the Investigation table. My code looks correct however it will only delete the officer from the officers table and not from the investigation table. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
queryCurs.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON')

queryCurs.execute('''CREATE TABLE Cases
                  (CID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Type TEXT, Description TEXT, Location TEXT, Ward INT)''')


queryCurs.execute('''CREATE TABLE Officers
                   (OID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name TEXT, Team TEXT)''')

queryCurs.execute('''CREATE TABLE Investigation
                   ( CID INTEGER, OID INTEGER REFERENCES Officers(OID) ON DELETE CASCADE, DateInvolved DATE)''')

queryCurs = conn.cursor()


queryCurs.execute('''DELETE  FROM Officers WHERE OID = 1''')


createDb.commit()
createDb.close()
```

Comment: Works for me (after I've actually inserted some records).

Comment: That just adds to the confusion mate. Did you make any changes to the code at all?

Comment: I inserted some records, and checked that OID 1 got deleted: [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/984f3/2). Your code looks OK; show the actual problem.